# Hiding prices on the Woocommerce shop pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'm using WordPress with a WooCommerce plugin and I would like to hide the prices from the shop page (Eg. $20 - $50). I have tried researching it but I haven't found much relating to this problem.

I only want to hide the prices on the shop page, not the individual product pages.

Any help provided will be much appreciated.

Comment: you can try using css to hide the price item on particular pages

Comment: Php hooks in woocommerce offer many ways to make it… If you remove prices you should also replace add to cart buttons with a linked button to the product…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this simple hooked function that will remove all product prices from Woocommerce archive pages as shop, product category archives and product tag archives pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_woocommerce_loop_price', 2 );
function remove_woocommerce_loop_price() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.

[image]

If you want to only target Shop pages, you will have to make it this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_woocommerce_loop_price', 2 );
function remove_woocommerce_loop_price() {
    if( ! is_shop() ) return; // only on shop pages
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
}
```

**Updated:** You may also want to replace add to cart button by a linked button to the product in Shop and archives pages

```
// Replace add to cart button by a linked button to the product in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Not needed for variable products
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return $button;

    // Button text here
    $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );

    return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
}
```